# Adding applications to Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I install anaconda to my windows machine and my anaconda navigator page like this:
[my anaconda navigator page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRTJK.png)

but I want to use pycharm or visual studio rather than spyder. After a short research I found this:[pycharm app on anaconda navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJCeA.jpg)

And also pycharm has anaconda plugin: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/promo/anaconda/ 
Although I downloaded this, I still can't see pycharm app on anaconda navigator.

How can I add pycharm ide to my anaconda navigator?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The image you use to show your research can't be read because of low resolution. Make sure to use the `Image` tool when asking.

Comment: PyCharm for Anaconda is not an application for Anaconda. It is a version of PyCharm that has the Anaconda plug-in included, so it interfaces with conda environments but doesn't appear in the Anaconda homepage AFAIK. If someone else has managed it, I'd love to know how.

Comment: Actually I managed it but I dont know only work for me or certain solution. I reinstall pycharm to recommended folder and pycharm appear on Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It doesn’t make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think init pycharm from Anaconda Navigator makes any sense. If you want to use conda in pycharm, just set the interpreter to conda.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it on my Mac for VSCode, PyCharm & DataSpell (assumes you already have the requisite applications installed):

1. Top LHS: Anaconda Navigator => Preferences; you'll get a window that looks like this:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzRNb.png
2. scroll to the bottom; it will look like this:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DszjN.png
3. Enter the path to the desired applications; when done, hit the "Apply" button.
4. Kill and re-start Navigator.

Here's the resulting Navigator page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gdVu.png